# Navbar goes unwanted transparent after scrolling over Article

Tags: html, css

I narrowed tmy issue down to the CSS Line `position:relative;` and if I remove it, it works, but then the category cat-work (Blue label) is shown at the top left. Idk how to fix it to be honest. Here the Code on Codepen ;

http://codepen.io/Allkind/pen/YXEjXX

```
    article{
    width:auto;
    min-height:10em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    margin: 1em;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    }
```

Note : Yes the Picture is too big but I tried it with others - same result. So someone might be able to have a better solution then remove the Label?^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not transparent, your navbar is being overlapped by the `article` tag. To fix that set `z-index` in your navbar.

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  z-index: 2; /* the z-index */
}
```

[Working Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waPxWe)